# MongoDB get only matching fields from array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to make distinc query. my collection is readData

```
 {"searchPhrases" : [
            "cheap samsung mobile",
            "red nokia 2mp"
        ]
    }

  { "searchPhrases" : [
        "red peter england shirt",
        "redish lee pant"
    ]
}
```

I tried query like `db.readData.distinct("searchPhrases",{"searchPhrases":"cheap samsung mobile"});`
It gives me out Put like `[ "cheap samsung mobile", "red nokia 2mp" ]` but I am expecting output like [ "cheap samsung mobile"]. I can't iterate it manually because its important data for search. And its huge collection so. Is their any other way using distinct?

Comment: Have you looked at [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use aggregation framework, If yes the you could do something like below

```
db.readData.aggregate(
 { $match: {"searchPhrases": { $in : ["cheap samsung mobile"] } } },
 { $unwind: $searchPhrases }, 
 { $match: {"searchPhrases": { $in : ["cheap samsung mobile"] } } },
 { $group: { _id:"$searchPhrases" } }
)
```

This might not be the exact code. For references look here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/